# .Net - "Thread is blocked/waiting" meaning for I/O bound operation

Tags: .net, multithreading, clr

Caller waiting for method to return back and till it is not returning, we can say thread is waiting, right ? However, this behaviour is because that inner method is waiting for some other operation or inner method in call stack to complete and return back. I am trying to visualize the behaviour of final operation which is holding the control to return back. In context of CLR, does it pause the execution flow (how ?) I might be overthinking, but for example if I am making network I/O call - so is it like CLR will wait for some signal once I/O operation is complete and will return back to caller ?

Now going little deep on highlighted

> "CLR will wait for some signal once I/O operation is complete and will
>   return back to caller"

does it means instruction pointer is stuck to specific instruction in stack till I/O is not complete. I think yes, so what that specific instruction is like and how it co-ordinates with signal when I/O completes.

Comment: http://mattwarren.org/2017/03/23/Hitchhikers-Guide-to-the-CoreCLR-Source-Code/

Comment: @Ewan maybe you can be more specific. That link points to a large page.

Comment: Firstly, you need to specify which API you are speaking of exactly. In windows, there is a concept of IO completion port, and some API's don't hide that much. They fire a callback or event when something occurs there. Secondly, there are the async/await keywords, that capture the state of a call at that time, inside object fields, so that the code can be resumed at a later point. This is not quite the same as saving the stack and the instruction pointer; it is a form of continuation.

Comment: @FrankHileman thx !! actually this question popped up while i was trying to understand implementation of `async/await` feature. I realized it basically boils down to continuation form and `TaskCompletionSource` using `SetResult` or `SetException` when asynchronous operation completes.

Comment: @FrankHileman : also regarding first point _They fire a callback or event when something occurs there_  if synchronous call is made for I/O  work, I understand your point that API will fire call back when that completes..but what happens to execution flow till it receives notification..I mean being synchronous it won't return back to caller, right ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal A truly synchronous call blocks the thread in the process. Other threads can proceed. Blocking a thread does mean saving the stack etc.